# Theoretically, would anti-gravity have a temporal component and if so what would that be?

Tags: gravity, time, spacetime-dimensions

This is purely speculative since we don’t know if we can actually create anti-gravity. Gravity and Time are two of the biggest mysteries in our universe. We don’t know why gravity is so weak or where it comes from and we aren’t really sure if time is real. Because of time dilation there is evidence that time and gravity are linked. Yet this also seems illogical when you think about it. How can these two work together.

Now if scientists figured out anti-gravity; would utilizing it also have a temporal component? If so; what would that be?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: ??? Gravity is a byproduct of mass. I don’t really understand your question.

Comment: We are sure time is real.

Comment: Doesn't seem illogical to anyone who's studied relativity. Seems weird and counter to everyday experience though. Takes a bit of getting your head around, you might say.. Not sure what the question is here. Can you clarify what it is you're trying to achieve, then we can help you get there - as just asking hypotheticals without context doesn't really get us anywhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> We don’t know (...) where it [gravity] comes from...

It is generally accepted that it comes from the mass in particles.

> Because of time dilation there is evidence that time and gravity are linked.

Slow down a little bit. This is only true for some values of "linked".

Time can exist without gravity. I won't write a wall of text here, but I will link to the wiki for [Minkowski space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_space)
. TL;DR: even in a universe with no gravity at all (for example, our own universe during its earliest moments), time still passes.

Now, when Einstein formulated special relativity, he assumed that gravity was equivalent to an accelerating reference frame. This is called *the equivalence principle*. TL;DR analogy: inside a closed box, you generally wouldn't be able to tell if you are on a planet, or inside an accelerating ship, just by your sensation of gravity alone.

It just so happens that the stronger this acceleration is, the more the rate of flow of time is perceived as slower by distant observers.

Now for the problem you propose. [This is the equation for time dilation factor caused by a massive, non-rotating sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_time_dilation#Outside_a_non-rotating_sphere). It is a very simplified descriptor for what you would get if you had a sphere of negative mass in space and its effects on an object you'd be observing:

$$\sqrt{1-\frac{\text{2 G M}}{\text{c}^2\text{ r}}}$$

Where $G$ is the gravitational constant, $M$ is the mass of the sphere, $c$ is the speed of light and $r$ is a Schwarzschild coordinate which for simplification we will assume to be the distance from the observed body to the center of the sphere.

Play with it around a little bit. You will see that for small values, such as $M$ = 1, inverting the signal causes the flow of the rate of time to increase. In other words, a sufficiently distant observer would see your clock accelerate rather than decelerate as expected.

Keep adding negative mass and it just makes time go faster, but it never reverses. In order to revert time you would instead need three things:

1. A sufficiently large amount of **positive** mass, so that $2GM > c^2r$
2. Allow for imaginary time, because the factor you would get would be the square root of a negative number.
3. Magic, because you would probably be inside a black hole's event horizon.

Comment: There is something so right about the square cube law explaining the workings of other laws.

Comment: Why does the sphere have to be massive for the equation to work?

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica it doesn't. But if you plug in a massless sphere, you get no time dilation either.

Answer (score 4):

### Yes and no

Gravity warps spacetime. Presumably, if it's possible to exert a negative amount of gravitational force, spacetime could be warped the other direction. If spacetime is warped in the other direction, the arrow of time might be affected.

Can gravity have a negative value? It is possible the answer is "no." Consider that temperature can have no negative value. Temperature is just particle motion, and the lowest temperature that's even theoretically possible is total absence of motion (0 Kelvin). There is no such thing as "negative-motion." Perhaps the situation with gravity is similar.

Another potential problem is that spacetime might not be capable of bending in the other direction. (I feel this is a distinct possibility from the previous point.) This might mean that anti-gravity can be used to negate gravity, but not to reverse it. In that case, anti-gravity could be real and useful, and would have a temporal component, but with significant limits.

Even in the best case, where negative gravitational force is possible, and spacetime can flex in the other direction, I would not expect anything like reversing time to become possible. The arrow of time points in its current direction because of entropy, which can only operate in one direction (unlike most other physical laws). That fact is played out at the subatomic scale throughout the universe. The operation of those systems isn't really affected by gravity: it's the weakest force. Stuff like chemistry is generally unaffected whether it's happening in a very deep gravity well or in the relatively flat spaces between stars and planets.

So, I think the temporal "component" of anti-gravity would almost certainly be just a lessening of the regular temporal component of gravity, with the consequence that the most extreme temporal effects that could be obtained would be to recreate the conditions of very flat regions of spacetime.

I've heard it said that one reason humans often struggle to grapple with relativity is because we evolved in a comparatively flat region of spacetime. If "perfect flatness" is indeed the most extreme effect of anti-gravity (by either my 2nd or 3rd arguments), then the result might be practically indistinguishable from everyday conditions here on Earth. (With the usual caveats for people working on GPS technology.)

Comment: 'The arrow of time' and 'entropy' are essentially the same thing. Some attributes of the construct 'time' form the 'definition' of 'entropy', while other attributes form the 'definition' of 'the arrow of time', with many overlaps. Space/time and space/entropy define the same thing. (The units of c are distance/time, so it is space/time, not spacetime). The 'arrow of time' does not point in the direction BECAUSE of 'entropy', but because they are two sides of the same coin.

Comment: Would it make sense to talk about a pocket of relative antigravity if we were somehow able to stress spacetime arbitrarily around the pocket?